# How to JOIN two columns with one serialized data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'am trying to build an eshop with multicategory support for products, so whenever I select a specific categories from `<select>`, I `serialize()` them and save them into DB.

So for now, I would like to output the JOINed tables with all db datas I need by trying to join two tables: `CATEGORIES` and `ECOMMERCE_PRODUCTS` in my `app/models/ecommerce_model.php`:

```
$this->db
    ->select('
            ecommerce_products.id,
            categories.id AS catid,
            categories.title AS categories,
            ecommerce_products.manid,
            ecommerce_products.name
        ')
    ->join('categories', 'ecommerce_products.catid = categories.id', 'left');
    ->join('categories as man', 'ecommerce_products.manid = man.id', 'left');
    $this->db->get('ecommerce_products')->result();
```

First JOIN stands for product categories, the second JOIN stands for product manufacturers which are also stored in `categories` table.

So to clarify, `ecommerce_products.catid` which is called inside the first JOIN is serialized, and I wonder how to unserialize it before doing a JOIN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is. You could store the IDs of categories as a string in the following format:

```
2,4,5,10,...
```

Then, use a combination of [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL functions to check the existence of `categories.id` in `ecommerce_products.catid`:

```sql
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(ecommerce_products.catid,
        ',',
        FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, ecommerce_products.catid)
), ',', -1)
```

To select the categories titles for each product record, we need to concatenate the titles by [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, So the final query would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       p.catid
       GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title ORDER BY cat.id SEPARATOR '|') as 'categories',
       p.manid,
       p.name
FROM ecommerce_products AS p
LEFT JOIN categories AS cat
    ON cat.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.catid, ',', FIND_IN_SET(cat.id, p.catid)), ',', -1)
-- more query...
GROUP BY p.id; -- Group the result to concatenate the categories titles
```

In this approach, you might need to use [`$this->db->query();`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) method to run the query manually.

**Note:**
As an alternative, you could use the following for `ON` statement:

```sql
LEFT JOIN categories AS cat
    ON p.catid REGEXP CONCAT('[,]{0,1}', cat.id, '[,]{0,1}')
```

### Test-case

Here is my test-case on **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57dae/6/0)**:

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.title ORDER BY c.id SEPARATOR '|') as 'categories'
FROM products as p
JOIN categories as c
  ON c.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.cat_id, ',', FIND_IN_SET(c.id, p.cat_id)) , ',', -1)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

#### Result:

```
ID    NAME          CATEGORIES
--    ---------     -----------
1     Product 1     Cat 1|Cat 3
2     Product 2     Cat 2|Cat 4
3     Product 3     Cat 1|Cat 4
4     Product 4     Cat 2|Cat 3
```

Comment: Great, Great, Great ! I feel lucky today, I was searching for this solution fro long time . Thanks a lot .. :-)

Comment: @Hashem Qolami : When i using this join with multiple tables (i.e) similary i have more that one columns with comma separated values  so when i using multiple joins data are getting repeated , what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case is bad solution to serialize ecommerce_products.catid`s which would later be used for joining tables. Unknown as will be used  serialized data in the future and what problems may arise: look, you already have a problem with a simple select with joins.

So while no later, I would advise to reconsider that approach. I think, in this specify moment the most optimal solution is to add third table `categories2ecommerce_products` with two fields: `category_id` and `ecom_product_cat_id` (for example). It will connect (relate) categories with ecommerce_products by theirs ids ( create table of ties ).

Comment: I just was thinking about this approach too, and probably will move on with this method. Thank you for your post