# How to left join serialize / unserialize

Tags: php

One of my columns have serialized data and I'm trying to left join do I need to unserialize 1st or how it's done? I didn't find a right way anywhere.

My query

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM damask_frontend LEFT JOIN damask_name ON (damask_frontend.damask_id = damask_name.id ) WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

so damask_frontend.damask_id is serialized data

```
a:6:{i:0;s:3:"150";i:1;s:3:"151";i:2;s:3:"152";i:3;s:3:"148";i:4;s:3:"147";i:5;s:3:"168";}
```

but damask_name.id is not serialized data 
so how can I match this query?

Comment: *"One of my columns have serialized data"* This is a wrongly designed database. Think about [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (Storing serialized datas is against the purpose of using a DB, indexing...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to JOIN two columns with one serialized data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134904/how-to-join-two-columns-with-one-serialized-data)

Comment: ok i understand now where is my mistake